# Reports for engaged subscribers

Tags: custom-reports, digital-engagement

I am looking for a way to find the amount of my subscribers who are highly engaged and those who are not engaged and haven’t opened an email in maybe a month or two, or past five emails. Can anyone share how they find this data (without queries).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send mail to the most engaged subscribers you can extract 'Subscriber Engagement' or 'Subscriber Most Recent Activity' report which displays a list of all subscribers and details who are mostly engaged.

Later, extract 'Unengaged Subscriber For A List' report which displays subscribers who are unresponsive after multiple email sends.

Check related references [Unengaged Subscribers for a List](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_unengaged_subscribers_for_a_list_report.htm&type=5), [Report in Analytics Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_create_a_report.htm&type=5), [Subscriber Engagement](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_re_subscriber_engagement_report.htm&type=5) here.

Thanks